# use 3dsmax python api get the vertex weight bone count

Tags: 3dsmax

I want to use 3dsmax python api to get skeletal mode is vertex weight bone count like this:

```
from pymxs import runtime as rt
import MaxPlus
max_root = MaxPlus.Core.GetRootNode()
#get the mesh node
mesh_node = max_root.GetChild(0)
#there is only one modifier  the skin modifier 
mod = mesh_node.GetModifier(0)  
#get the first vertex  weight count
weight_count = rt.skinOps.GetVertexWeightCount(mod, 0)
```

i get this error:

```
Unable to convert: Animatable(Skin) to type: Modifier.
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: formatting changes

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do is:

```py
from pymxs import runtime as rt
import MaxPlus

# Get the selected node (must be a mesh)
mesh_node = MaxPlus.SelectionManager.GetNodes()[0]

# Get the skin
skin = rt.getnodebyname(mesh_node.Name).skin

# Get the bone count
bone_count = rt.skinOps.GetNumberBones(skin)
print(bone_count)

# Get the first vertex  weight count
weight_count = rt.skinOps.GetVertexWeightCount(skin, 1)
print(weight_count)
```

I hope it will help anyone who come across this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine pymxs and MaxPlus this way, one is a MAXScript runtime engine, the other is a wrapper around C++ SDK and native objects. I mean, you could pass around pointers and handles and convert the objects to and from those but it's much easier to just stick to one of those.